# Grouping a dataframe according to occurence of one value

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to clean some data which were in a funny format. Basically the dataframe looks like this:

```
 1     2     3
NaN | a   | b   |
    |foo  | bar |
    |foo2 | bar2|
NaN | c   | d   |
    |foo3 | bar3|
```

And every time I have a NaN in column 1, I would like to fill the column with a combination of what I have in column a and b, until I meet another NaN. Finally I want to get rid of that row containing the NaN.

The resulting data frame would look like:

```
 1     2     3
a_b |foo  | bar |
a_b |foo2 | bar2|
c_d |foo3 | bar3|
```

I managed to get what I want by parsing strings but the code is huge and I am sure there is a faster way to do it using pandas.

This is my first post on SO, I apologize if I am not clear or not following the writing standards and especially if the title is not that explicit. I will appreciate any comment to make me improve.

Comment: Please show us what you have tried so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try something like this if those NaN really are null values:

```
df['key']=df['1'].isnull().cumsum()

df_header = df[df['1'].isnull()]

df_out = df_header.merge(df[df['1'].notnull()], on='key',suffixes=('_x','')).set_index(['2_x','3_x'])

df_out.index = df_out.index.map('_'.join)

df_out.drop(['1_x','key','1'],axis=1).rename_axis(['1']).reset_index()
```

Output:

```
    1       2      3
0   a_b     foo     bar 
1   a_b     foo2    bar2
2   c_d     foo3    bar3
```

Comment: Wow thank you @Scott Boston `.cumsum()` is exactly what I was looking for to unlock me! then it makes it easy to do anything such as `groupby()` and so on (I wish I could upvote your answer). I would be curious if you have any idea how to handle a specific value "A" and not null values? (assuming that column 1 has "A" values in the middle of other random values, in which case `.cumsum` is not helping)

Comment: You can do the same, since isnull returns a true or false, you can change that out to something like (df['1'] == 'A').cumsum().  Those true of false get converted to int ie.. 1 or 0 and cumsum just sums it up over the column.

Comment: Alright, that so clear ;) I was thinking about replacing the "A" values by NaN to be able to use `isnull()`... I have so much to learn. Thx again for your help @Scott Boston

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using the function [fillna](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html).

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

#df test
l = ["foo",
"foo2",
"foo3",
"foo4" ]
df = pd.DataFrame(l)
df[1] = [np.nan for i in range(3)]+[1]
df[2] = ["bar"+str(i)for i in range(4)]

#Filling the nan with the additionned value of the two colums
df[1] = df[1].fillna(df[2]+df[0])
```

input

```
    0       1   2
0   foo     NaN bar0
1   foo2    NaN bar1
2   foo3    NaN bar2
3   foo4    1.0 bar3
```

output

```
    0       1           2
0   foo     bar0foo     bar0
1   foo2    bar1foo2    bar1
2   foo3    bar2foo3    bar2
3   foo4    1.0         bar3
```